# CSS - the correct way to align an image alongside two divs

Tags: html, css

This must be really basic but it has been doing my head in.
Here is a basic image of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

I have a container div with a 100% width.
I have a piece of text which I put in a paragraph tag and below that some input fields and a button. All of this should centered.
I have an image which should be just to the right of both the text and the fields and is roughly the same height as both of these divs.

When the viewport resizes larger the image should stay anchored to the end of the text and input fields - around 20px away. If I float the container with a  % width it will keep drifting further as the windowsize increases?

I have tried the following:

- an outer div for a container and two inner divs, one floated left (containing the text and inputs), the other right (with the image)
- an outer container with 3 separate divs inside, 1 for the text line which is 100% width, followed by another for the input fields width 70%, final div width 30% for the image.
- a container with one div inside it. the text and the image inside the paragraph and manually positioning the image, followed by the input fields.

and many other similar variations and yet somehow I still can't get what I'm looking for.

What is the correct way to do this? It seems so simple yet continues to elude me after hours of fiddling. 
Please keep in mind that this code will exist inside a responsive template and so I am not looking to work with fixed values or positioning. I will need to restyle the inputs to stack on top of each other with the image on the right once resized to a mobile breakpoint (but for now that is irrelevant I think).

Any help is much appreciated for this task that is making me feel increasingly stupid! I must be missing something fairly basic..
Here is a fiddle example that anyone can feel free to edit. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL3nns1c/)

```css
.inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:beige;
}

.myImage {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="textSignup">
      Get the latest tips on an interesting subject and a FREE extract from our Guide
      <img class="myImage" src="http://www.vapld.info/images/ys/books.png" width="100" height="65">
    </p>

    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your first name" id="firstName">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" size="11" placeholder="Your email" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Download my free ebook">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the image a set size or anything?

Comment: ya its about 90x 60 and should keep those proportions. In the example given I threw in a placeholder image with the size of 100x 65 as I can't embed my own img into a post yet

Comment: try vertical-align:middle for images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do :

- Float your `.myImage` to the right
- Add a [**clearfix**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to `.inner`

---

#### Demo

```css
.inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 560px;
}
  
.inner:before,.inner:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.inner:after {
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:beige;
}
  
.textSignup {
    padding-bottom : 15px;
}

.myImage {
   padding-top: 10px;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="textSignup">
      Get the latest tips on an interesting subject and a FREE extract from our Guide
      <img class="myImage" src="http://www.vapld.info/images/ys/books.png" width="100" height="65">
    </p>

    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your first name" id="firstName">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" size="11" placeholder="Your email" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Download my free ebook">
  </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d0f6jnzd/3/))

Comment: Thx @John   - it is very close. The only problem I see there is the floating of the image the right means when the viewport size increases the image is always pulled further to the right - how do I get it to stay close to the other content so that all stays in the center of the screen. Is my only option to create another container with a fixed width to keep it inside of?

Comment: @Sharks : Why not just add a `max-width` to your `.inner`? See my updated answer (or the updated Fiddle) for a demo.

Comment: Ok @John , that definitely gets me a lot closer. It creates some minor spacing issues which I can mostly get rid of by editing my paddings. I'm not 100% sure what the clear-fix has done to change things but I guess that's something for me to read up on, and yes of course the fixed width on the existing div works. I now have almost exactly what I wanted so thx a lot for your help and the others who answered also

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like [this](https://codepen.io/snvl1993/pen/PNmmme)

HTML

```css
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="textSignup">
        Get the latest tips on an interesting subject and a FREE extract from our Guide
      </p>

      <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your first name" id="firstName">
      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" size="11" placeholder="Your email" required="">
      <input type="submit" value="Download my free ebook">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img class="myImage" src="http://www.vapld.info/images/ys/books.png" width="100" height="65">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This looks very close. I forked your pen and changed `.right` to `text-align:right` and added a 30px margin-left to `.right img` :  https://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/eZWWyN?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/vytnLbdu/

I've got an output that looks a lot like your mockup.
We've simply moved your image into the second column of a 2-column container. The line between your text and input fields are done with a `<br>` tag.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p class="textSignup">Get the latest tips on an interesting subject and a FREE extract from our Guide</p><br>
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your first name" id="firstName">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" size="11" placeholder="Your email" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Download my free ebook">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://www.vapld.info/images/ys/books.png" width="100"     height="65">
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.left 
  {
      float: left;
      width: 60%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align:center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .right{
    width:40%;
    float:right;
  }

  .container 
  {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:beige;
  }

  .myImage 
  {
   padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Thx DrSatan1 for the input - yes it does look very similar and is similar to what I had also. I do see two problems currently - it doesn't seem to be respecting the container bg color (unsure why this is) and it isn't centered on the page. PLus when the viewport resizes the % value given to the image div means that the image gets pulled further away, whereas I want it to stay anchored to teh end of the text and input fields  - around 20px away - sorry if I didn't make that clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline-block with absolute positioning to achieve something similar to your design. A point to note, however, there is no 'right' way of doing things in web design - there are just some approaches that 'should be avoided if possible'.

```css
.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
}
.myImage {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    Get the latest tips on an interesting subject and a FREE extract from our Guide
    <img class="myImage" src="http://www.vapld.info/images/ys/books.png" width="100" height="65">

    <br>
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Your first name" id="firstName">
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" size="11" placeholder="Your email" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Download my free ebook">

  </div>

</div>
```